# Can't configure Inbound/Outbound on Issabel

Tags: asterisk

I have PRI line connected to E1 card. I installed Issabel with Asterisk11 on it. Whenever I try to call the number given to us by the PRI provider, I find the number busy.

I tried to configure inbound route to match all DID and CID and route the call to some extension I have created. I logged in with the extension's credentials on Zoiper (softphone) but I never receive the call. I can't find anything in the logs either about the missing calls.

I tried to try outbound call through Dahdi but I always receive this message "Everyone is busy/congested at this time"

Any idea why?

Comment: It would be helpful to set the output of the following commands:
pri show span & 
pri debug span